# getelements - Appium, doesn't work for several elements

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, getelementsbyname

I'm trying to get all elemetns and their values.
I have a table with several items in it (IOS)

All the items within the table have the same name but different values, while I'm trying to get elements in one try by using

```
List<WebElement> l = driver.findElements(By.name(name));
```

and then iterating trough the list and pulling the value by

```
for(int i =0; i < l.length; i++){
 String val = ((MobileElement) l.get(i)).getAttribute("value");
}
```

I'm getting the correct value only on first iteration (first element) , all others are return empty value...

if I'm changing the code to :

```
        //1
        List<WebElement> l = driver.findElements(driver, By.name(name));
        String val = ((MobileElement) weList.get(0)).getAttribute("value");

        //2
        l = driver.findElements(driver, By.name(name));
        val = ((MobileElement) weList.get(1)).getAttribute("value");

        //3
        l = driver.findElements(driver, By.name(name));
        val = ((MobileElement) weList.get(2)).getAttribute("value");
```

I'm getting the correct values.

It seems that I need to pull the element each time I'm trying to access it.
Is it a bug , or I just miss something ?

Comment: Did U checks  if conversion to Mobile element is possible (by instanceof)?

Comment: It possible , as I described , I do able to pull the element only if I executing the "findElements" for each element I pulling and then I have correct element's value. If I executing the findElements only once , and then trying to iterate, I'm getting an empty value.

Comment: show code for iteration.

Comment: for(int i =0; i < l.length; i++){
    if(l.get(i)).instanceOf(MobileElement)){
       String val = ((MobileElement) l.get(i)).getAttribute("value");
println val;//syso in Java
     }
   }

Comment: check code above and post result

Comment: @SkorpEN : First thanks , it worked , second , PLS explain the idea behind , all of the list items were instanceof MobileElements , there were 3 list items and 3 iterations ... So why actually it works like that ?

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i =0; i < l.length; i++){    
 if(l.get(i)).instanceOf(MobileElement)){
    String val = ((MobileElement) l.get(i)).getAttribute("value"); 
    println val;//syso in Java 
} }
```

It works becouse when U use `driver.findElements(By.name(name));` U get all elements that match name name.
But when U use `if(l.get(i)).instanceOf(MobileElement))` U operate only on elements, that are instance of MobileElement. Without it it is possible, that null or other strange element was written to val, and then rest not worked.

Comment: OK , Didn't work.
one more execution and the same problem is still there getting an empty value...

Comment: I really think that it's some Appium's bug

Comment: Did U wait for whole page to be fully loaded?
Add implicitWait 2 seconds before script.

Comment: No I didn't , I'll try , bit again , why it does work if I'm getting all list elements from scratch ?

Comment: becouse U got elements with name only that that U want. But in normal file U got also elements with name name that U not want.
change name to name2 if U can, or even more complicated name. Or use other more precise locator.

Comment: Didnt understand , If I inspect the UI , I see exact number of elements with the name , the same number I'm getting within the list.
Each time I'm trying to get the elements , I'm getting the same #